# Combining CSV Files with additional columns - and aligning columns

Tags: python, pandas

We have been receiving files from our counterparty for the past 3 years on a daily basis. So that means we have well over 1000 files now. Each of them have between 5000 to 15000 rows depending on the day.

I was trying to combine it in Python using some googling and research in Visual Studio Code. To test things out I took only the Files from the last day of each month. A total of 33 files.

The files are like this

```
File 1:

Header_1  Header_2      Header 3 
0         2             1
2         3             2 
4                       3  


File 2:     

Header_1   Header_4      Header_3  Header_2
6          4             3         1
8          5             4 
10

Desired Output
Header_1   Header_2   Header_3   Header_4 File_Name
0          2          1                   File 1
2          3          2                   File 1
4                     3                   File 1
6          1          3          4        File 2
8                     4          5        File 2
10
```

The code I used to try this is:

```
import os
import pandas as pd
import glob

#set working directory
os.chdir("/filepath/")

globbed_files = glob.glob("*.csv") #creates a list of all csv files
print(globbed_files)
data = [] # pd.concat takes a list of dataframes as an agrument
for csv in globbed_files:
    frame = pd.read_csv(csv)
    data.append(frame)
    print (frame) #to check while running whether the frame was correct


bigframe = pd.concat(data, ignore_index=True, keys=globbed_files) 
bigframe.to_csv("output.csv")
```

I can give up the File Names if needed and the empty cells can be NaN or just empty that's fine. But right now my header's aren't lining up and I will get completely mismatched columns.

Comment: It seems data related problem.

Comment: Are created DataFrame after `frame = pd.read_csv(csv)` correctly?

Comment: So from what I can see in the VSCode Terminal Input the frames seem to be created correctly.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your code seems to work. I just added the File_name column and rearranged columns

```
import pandas as pd
# you can use your own files here, I'm just using this to test
df1 = pd.DataFrame({"header_1":[1,2,3,4],"header_2": [2,3,4,6]})
df2 = pd.DataFrame({"header_4":[1,2,3,4],"header_3": [2,3,4,5]})

globbed_files = [df1,df2] #creates a list of all csv files
print(globbed_files)
data = [] # pd.concat takes a list of dataframes as an argument
i=1 # use this to set the file name counter
for csv in globbed_files:
    frame = csv
    frame["File_Name"] = "File " + str(i) # File_Name values are set here
    data.append(frame)
    i+=1

bigframe = pd.concat(data, ignore_index=True, keys=globbed_files)
bigframe = bigframe.reindex(sorted(df.columns), axis=1) # this arranges your columns alphabetically
bigframe = bigframe[ [ col for col in bigframe.columns if col != 'File_Name' ] + ['File_Name'] ] # takes File_Name column to the end
```